# How to Create a Query to select a record based on a Hierarchy - PROC SQL

Tags: sql, sas

I need to make a query that will pull records based on multiple maximum values in a group in a specific hierarchy.  I have a table that looks like this:

```
Key Classificaiton  set_ind  Date     Rank    Amount
1       1              1     5/2/2017   1     15
2       1              1     5/2/2017   3     2
3       1              0     4/2/2017   2     32
4       2              1     5/1/2017   2     5
5       2              1     1/5/2017   4     16
6       2              1     12/13/2016 1     12
7       2              0     12/13/2016 3     20
8       3              1     4/5/2017   2     15
9       3              0     4/8/2017   1     23
```

I need to be able to get the Key for every record that has a set_ind = 1, the most recent date, and the highest rank, in that order of hierarchy for each classification.

So from the sample table, the query would pull the record corresponding to key 2, 4 and 8.

I've tried using this code:

```
    proc sql;
    create table test as
     select key, classification, max(date), max(rank)
     from ods.data 
     where set_ind = 1
     group by 2, 1;
    quit;
```

I know I'm still getting dups in the classification because I have the key in the query, but I need the key to be able to identify the specific record.

I've also tried running two queries, one to find max(date) and then doing a right join on another query to find max(rank) but that hasn't worked either.

For both queries the data I need will have no dups in the Classification column and will have a key to go with each record.  When I run the code above, I get dups.  I'm not sure how to pull the data correctly.

Comment: So for classification 2: you chose the key as 4 based on max(date) but it does not have the highest rank. So you want highest date for each classification and its CORRESPONDING rank?

Comment: @G.Arima Not quite.  Think of  each classification as a set. Inside of each classification I have  a date. I make a subset of the highest date from each classificatoin.  Then if there are multiple records with the highest date, I choose the higest rank from that subset of the highest dates for the classifications.  I hope that makes sense.

Comment: Yes it perfectly does. I have answered the query on this logic only. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using SAS. Giving you a efficient way of doing the problem in data step.
**Step1:** **Sort** the data by classification,date,rank
**Step2:** Pick last record of each classification by **first.** so as to obtain the max dates against each classification. Incase the dates are same then picking the max of rank.

```
proc sort data =abc;
by Classificaton Date  rank;
run;

data abc1;
set abc(where=(set_ind=1));
by Classificaton Date  rank;
if last.Classificaton ;
drop amount set_ind;
run;
```

**My Output:**

```
|Key    |Classificaton   |Date       |Rank
|2      |1               |5/2/2017   |3
|4      |2               |5/1/2017   |2
|8      |3               |4/5/2017   |2
```

Let me know in case of any queries.

Comment: Worked without a problem, thank you!  I just figured out a way to do it using proc sql, so I'll post that for reference, but this is a much better way to solve it in SAS.

Comment: Looking forward for that sql solution. You are welcome. Happy to help :)

Answer (score 2):

Subqueries like this leave me hesitant to post this answer, but it'll work for you. I'm really interested in seeing a better answer, though!

```
select *
from ods.data
where set_ind = 1
and date = (select max(Date) from ods.data where set_ind=1)
and rank = (select max(Rank) from ods.data where set_ind=1 and date=(select max(Date) from ods.data where set_ind=1))
```

Edit: I had a brain fart, and copied and pasted my test query, without replacing it with your table's schema. I've corrected the query with the appropriate table/column names.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to solve this problem using proc sql, even though a better solution for SAS has been presented.

I first created a table that pulls the max values for date and rank, but has duplicate classifications:

```
proc sql;
create table max_info as
select classification
      ,max(date) as date
      ,max(rank) as rank
from ods.data
where set_ind = 1
group by 1;
quit;
```

I then go to the original table and find the records that match the classification, max date and max rank with this code:

```
proc sql;
create table max as
select *
from ods.data a
right join work.max_info b on a.classification = b.classification and 
                              a.date = b.date and 
                              a.rank = b.rank
where set_ind = 1;
quit;
```

Answer (score 0):

No database type mentioned.

In Vertica (and I think Postgres, too), you can do it like below.
They support the LIMIT clause with OLAP window expression:

```
WITH
-- input as from question, don't use in real query ...
input(Key,classification,set_ind,Date,Rank,Amount) AS (
          SELECT 1,1,1,DATE '5/2/2017'  ,1,15
UNION ALL SELECT 2,1,1,DATE '5/2/2017'  ,3,2
UNION ALL SELECT 3,1,0,DATE '4/2/2017'  ,2,32
UNION ALL SELECT 4,2,1,DATE '5/1/2017'  ,2,5
UNION ALL SELECT 5,2,1,DATE '1/5/2017'  ,4,16
UNION ALL SELECT 6,2,1,DATE '12/13/2016',1,12
UNION ALL SELECT 7,2,0,DATE '12/13/2016',3,20
UNION ALL SELECT 8,3,1,DATE '4/5/2017'  ,2,15
UNION ALL SELECT 9,3,0,DATE '4/8/2017'  ,1,23
)
-- end of input, real query starts here
SELECT
  *
FROM input
WHERE set_ind=1
LIMIT 1 OVER(PARTITION BY classification ORDER BY date DESC, rank DESC)
;

Key|classification|set_ind|Date      |Rank|Amount
  2|             1|      1|2017-05-02|   3|     2
  4|             2|      1|2017-05-01|   2|     5
  8|             3|      1|2017-04-05|   2|    15
```